# How to do the plumber::plumb(file = 'mypath') in httr?

Tags: r, httr, plumber

I am struggling to find a solution that httr can do the same thing as plumber in R. In plumber here's the code that works:

1). Create a script hello_world_plumber.R

```
#' @post /hello_world
hi <- function(name) {
  return(paste0('Hello ', name, '!'))
}
```

2). In another script:

```
pr <-  plumb(file = '~/hello_world_plumber.R')
pr$run(swagger = F)

Starting server to listen on port 5852
Running the swagger UI at http://127.0.0.1:5852/__swagger__/
```

3). In the terminal

```
curl -s --data 'Matt' http://127.0.0.1:5852/hello_world
```

```
Out: Hello Matt!
```

Comment: So you're trying to do `plumber` serving of API endpoints completely in `httr`? Is that reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Is it that difficult to do what plumber does purely in httr? httr has way more daily downloads, so it makes me feel like plumber can get deprecated easily.

Comment: I might be misguided, but I tend to think of `httr`'s strength in *retrieving* data (possibly with attached data), not *serving* data. `plumber` is doing a *lot* of handling under the hood, on top of merely answering queries with the output from an R function. I'm sure you could glue together some of `httpuv` to serve things in a different and perhaps smaller way.

Comment: (BTW: I don't see any functions in `httr`, exported or internal, that include a semblance of "serve". That's not definitive by any stretch, and I'm not a guru on `httr`, but it is a data point.)

Comment: I'm new to this as well.. I might be misguided too

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1053/. Either I'm part of the 10000 or you are, I don't know yet which :-) (All too many times I've been *certain* about something until somebody proved how wrong I was.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plumber` is built on top of the `httpuv` library to help you define an API quickly with a few decorations.

`httr` package is to send http queries via the curl command.

So `httr` is like a client and `plumber` is your server. That's why there is more downloads. There is way more Chrome/Firefox download than Nginx/Apache, it is just the nature of the tools.

You could achieve the same thing without plumber just using `httpuv` if you don't care about decoration, async, query string and body parsing, openapi and other goodies. it is pretty bare though.

```r
runServer("127.0.0.1", 8477,
  list(
    call = function(req) {
      list(
        status = 200L,
        headers = list(
          'Content-Type' = 'text/html'
        ),
        body = "Hello world!"
      )
    }
  )
)
```

There are multiple `plumber` alternatives too, `RestRserve`, `OpenCPU` to name a few.

Depending on your use case, you select what works best for you. If you need any plumber help, feel free to ask. I don't see it going away soon as it has been incorporated into RStudio IDE and I think it's decoration structure a la `roxygen2` makes it simple to adopt.

Comment: Wow great thanks for the detailed answer! plumber looks great and I hope it doesn't get deprecated like many other R packages that were widely used (ehm caret)

Comment: I believe `caret` has a sibling `parsnip` in the tidyverse. In the space `caret` and `parsnip` are playing, you can get behind cutting edge in a matter of months, and it is entirely subjective to your work. Both packages are still updated more frequently than some paid software.

Comment: Hey @Bruno Tremblay I just posted another plumber question. It'd be great if you knew how to solve that one! Thanks